# No "File Search" tab in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I don't know how this happened, but the "File Search" tab disappeared from my Eclipse Search Dialog window, and  don't know how to get it back! Here is a screenshot of how it looks like on my computer:

[image: My Search Dialog window]

I have Eclipse Luna 4.4 and I'm running Linux, for that matters. Anyone knows how this could have occurred and whether it could be a bug in Eclipse or not?

Comment: There might be some error message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory

Comment: Check whether is there any menu item called **File...** under the main menu item **Search**

Comment: @Chandrayya: Nope, there is only a C/C++ entry ...

Comment: @greg-449: The .log message contains a lot of stuff. I don't really know what to look for. Do you know the name of the component for the File Search Dialog?

Comment: File search is TextSearchPage in SearchDialog

Comment: Ok, there is no mention of TextSearchPage nor SearchDialog in my .log file ... damn.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing plugins one by one and see if you can get to a point where it comes back.  On my machine the eclipse-linuxtools plugin was somehow preventing the File Search tab from coming up.